# Dropdown not working. Why do I get a data validation error?

Tags: excel

I'm working with a template that has formula which displays drop down list. In this template, I'm copying over several plans that have already picked an item from the drop down list. However, when the plan is copied over, the data validation error occurs and if I want to change the item from the drop down menu, I'm not able to do that. Can you please advice how can I sync the data with the formulas created already?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

When I click on the arrow, the list is not displaying.

Comment: What is your data validation setting for that cell?

Comment: Are you using named ranges as the data validation list formula? If you copied an entire sheet, you'll automatically be creating a new duplicate named range, except the scope will be the sheet only, not the workbook to avoid clashing. This could cause this issue.

Comment: I looked again at the list rule. When I paste new rows in the column, the current rule is not applied for them automatically. What I did was to create a list again for the column. I clicked on the header-> data validation> selected list-> then enumerated all options. Works fine now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it myself with help of comments under my questions. When I paste new rows in the column, the current rule is not applied for them automatically. What I did was to create a list again for the column. I clicked on the column header-> data validation> selected list-> then added all options/items for the list. I can change value of pasted items.